# Assistance with cs50p

Tags: python, cs50

Currently taking the first week of cs50p.I am having trouble finding the appropriate resources to help me finish this assignment.

I trying to complete the "Tip Calculator" problem, and this is what I have come up with so far:

```
def main():
    dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
    percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
    tip = dollars * percent
    print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")


def dollars_to_float(d):
    return(int(float((d))))




def percent_to_float(p):
    return(int(p))


main()
```

Most of the code was provided for us. All we had to do was "def dollars_to_float(d)" and "def percent_to_float". I was finally able to get my input for dollars and percent accepted, but only if I input the amount without the dollar sign. If I type "50.00" it works, but not if I type "$50.00". Same goes for the percent.

Lastly, I am struggling turn the percent given by the user into a decimal. So, if I type 15%, I would like it to become 0.15.

If I input "50.00" and "15" I get the answer of $750.00 but I am supposed to get an answer of $7.50.

I would really appreciate it if any of you could guide me to the correct answer/ guide me to the right resources rather than just providing me with the answer. I would really like to truly learn how to do this. Since I am just learning this, I have a hard time understanding the instructions on pythons website, otherwise I would just go there.

Thank you.

Comment: `percent_to_float()` should convert the input to a number and then divide by 100. You should have learned how percentages work in school.

Comment: `return int(p) / 100`

Comment: Why do you call `int()` in `dollars_to_float()`? That will discard the cents part of the cost.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Thank you! If you dont mind a final question, how would I remove the % and $ signs on this problem if the user where to type them? I think im having a syntax error. Not sure how to know where to include it

Comment: `d = d.replace('$', '')`

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a feeling it was .replace() but I was confused how to format it. I thought it was d.replace(' $ ', '') or d=.replace(' $ ', ''). It did not make sense to type d twice.

Answer (score 0):

you could actually do

```
def dollars_to_float(d):
    money = float(d.replace('$',''))
    return money


def percent_to_float(p):
    percent = float(p.replace("%","")) / 100
    return percent
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).